# Batch script to execute jobs one after the other using a GUID as an input argument

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, prompt, command-line-arguments

I would like to create a batch file which I can reuse with different GUID input parameters.

Normally, I execute a file 4 times, one after the other with varying input parameters like so:

```
D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test map 353c8be4-d3ca-4c92-96ee-ea1
4933f54fa
D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test compare 353c8be4-d3ca-4c92-96ee-ea1
4933f54fa
D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test analyse 353c8be4-d3ca-4c92-96ee-ea1
4933f54fa
D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test update 353c8be4-d3ca-4c92-96ee-ea1
4933f54fa
```

I would like to be able to pass in the GUID, as this is the only part that varies for different jobs

The following is what I have come up with but I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\f\Desktop>echo off
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

actual script:

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
shift
start /wait D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test map arg1=%1
start /wait D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test compare arg1=%1
start /wait D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test analyse arg1=%1
start /wait D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test update arg1=%1

pause
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### But I get the following errors

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
shift
start /wait D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test map arg1=%1
start /wait D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test compare arg1=%1
start /wait D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test analyse arg1=%1
start /wait D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test update arg1=%1
pause
```

Your script has many errors:

- `set arg1=%1`

  `arg1` is set and never used again.
- `shift`

  Why are you shifting? There is no need to.
- `start /wait D:\>Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe`

  `D:\>` is your command prompt and not part of the command
- `arg1=%1`

  Why are you doing this? What do you think it will achieve?

---

### Solution

Try the following batch file (doit.cmd):

```
@echo off
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test map %1
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test compare %1
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test analyse %1
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test update %1
pause
```

Call it as follows:

```
doit 353c8be4-d3ca-4c92-96ee-ea14933f54fa
```

---

#### Is there anyway I would be able to click on the bat file and be allowed to just enter the input?

Use `set /p`

- The `/p` switch allows you to set a variable equal to a line of input entered by the user.

  The Prompt string is displayed before the user input is read.

```
@echo off
set /p guid=Please enter GUID:
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test map %guid%
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test compare %guid%
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test analyse %guid%
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test update %guid%
pause
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, is there anyway I would be able to click on the bat file and be allowed to just enter the input, rather than having to navigate to the location and execute it through the command line?

Comment: @Xerxes Sure, answer updated

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, maybe you can help with my next issue? http://superuser.com/questions/961089/output-each-commands-results-into-a-separate-file?noredirect=1#comment1313640_961089