# Output each commands results into a separate file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, prompt

I have got the following script which executes a separate step one after the other:

```
@echo off
set /p guid=Please enter GUID:
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test map %guid%
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test compare %guid%
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test analyse %guid%
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test update %guid%
pause
```

I would like to log the output of each of these steps into its own text file preferably with a name that corresponds to the process being executed, so the following log files would be created:

```
map.txt
compare.txt
analyse.txt
update.txt
```

what would be even better is if the files had the date and time prepended to them:

```
2015-09-22 10:23:47.048_map.txt
2015-09-22 10:23:47.048_compare.txt
2015-09-22 10:23:47.048_analyse.txt
2015-09-22 10:23:47.048_update.txt
```

Comment: @joejoe31b Questions about batch files and command line programming are on topic here.

Comment: You need to start learning for yourself. - [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh, ok. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: [Format date and time in a Windows batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1192476)

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess that you've figured this out by now. For others who may have a similar question, here is an answer:

```
@echo off
set filePrefix=C:\%Date:~10,4%-%Date:~4,2%-%Date:~7,2%%time%_
set /p guid=Please enter GUID:
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test map %guid% > %filePrefix%map.txt
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test compare %guid% > %filePrefix%compare.txt
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test analyse %guid% > %filePrefix%analyse.txt
start /wait Drop\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test update %guid% > %filePrefix%update.txt
pause
```

Note that %date% and %time% may be formatted differently in different locales — %date% might or might not include the day of the week, and might possibly be dd/mm instead of mm/dd; %time% might be hh:mm:ss or something else (e.g., hh-mm-ss), possibly with fractional seconds (decimal point) — so this may need to be adjusted. The offsets into %date% (10, 4, & 7) may need to be adjusted to locate the year, month, and day. If %time% contains colons, you need to remove/replace them for Windows filenames, and the hour might have a leading space (instead of zero) between 1:00 and 9:59 AM.

Comment: Note that `%date%` and `%time%` may be formatted differently in different locales — `%date%` might or might not include the day of the week, and might possibly be dd/mm instead of mm/dd; `%time%` might be hh:mm:ss or something else (e.g., hh-mm-ss), possibly with fractional seconds (decimal point) — so this may need to be adjusted. The offsets into `%date%` (10, 4, & 7) may need to be adjusted to locate the year, month, and day. If `%time%` contains colons, you need to remove/replace them for Windows filenames, and the hour might have a leading space (instead of zero) between 1:00 and 9:59 AM.

Comment: There is much discussion in [su] question [Format date and time in a Windows batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1192476) on the locale issues, with several possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks, for the extra info Scott. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: @krowe this solution does not work, it doesnt create any files!

Comment: @Xerxes This definitely works. They are in the `c:\ `. You can change the destination to whatever you want it to be by changing the line which assigns a value to filePrefix.

Comment: @krowe there is no text in the files, they are absolutely empty, the output from individual processes has not been redirected into it's file.

Comment: @Xerxes: (1) Is the output from the commands showing up *anywhere* (e.g., on the screen or in another file)?  (2) If not, are you sure that your program ***has*** output?  (If you run it with no `> ` *`filename`*, do you get output to the screen?)  (3) And can that output ***be*** redirected?  Try running the commands with plain filenames, e.g., `> map.txt`, `> compare.txt`, etc., and verify that that works.  (4) You can get some insight into what your script is doing by commenting out the `echo off` command.  (5) Do you need to use `start /wait`?  What happens if you just *run* the program?

Comment: @Scott the commands definitely have their own outputs, they show up on the main batch execution screen, the steps have to run in order, one after the other, the main reason for this questions was to solve the redirection of the specific commands outputs into their own files because I wasn't able to do it myself after trying everything from what I have gathered this script will output the main batch output into the files and not the specific steps outputs.